# Retrieve row index from a databound link button

Tags: gridview

I have placed a link-button in certain cells while in rowdatabound event.

I cant though figure out how to retrieve the row index value from it when clicked. I have coded the link button in several variations of below.

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim ParentLink As LinkButton = New LinkButton
        If (e.Row.Cells(3).Text.Equals("&nbsp;")) Then
            e.Row.Cells(3).BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            ParentLink.Text = "Resend"
            ParentLink.ID = "Resend"
            ParentLink.CommandName = "Resend"
            ParentLink.CommandArgument = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()
            '  AddHandler ParentLink.Command, AddressOf resend_email
            e.Row.Cells(5).Controls.Add(ParentLink)
        End If
    End If
```

I have seen using "asp:TemplateField>", but no good examples when adding one this way.  When I click it comes back to the rowdatabound event, but I don't know how to get the commandargument or rowindex of the linkbutton. Show this young lad the error of his ways!

Answer (score 0):

Final code snippet that worked.

```
 Sub CustomersGridView_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    If e.CommandName = "Resend" Then
        Dim rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
        Dim Row = GridView1.Rows(rowIndex)
        loc_resend = Row.Cells(4).Text ' location
        custid_resend = Row.Cells(0).Text ' customer id
        name_resend = Row.Cells(1).Text ' customer name
        Ckbox_resend.Visible = True
        butResend.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```